# Ready-made forum, chat, and PM solutions for Django

Tags: django, chat, message, forum

On my Django site I would like users to communicate with each other in several ways:

1. Forum
2. Private messages
3. Chat with rooms and saved history

Could you suggest me ready solutions for this? Especially for chat.

Also, is it possible to integrate Google Wave in Django?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like [Pinax](http://pinaxproject.com/) would be a great fit for you.  It has most of what you've listed already bundled.

Comment: Pinax has private messages but I don't remember it having forums or chat with rooms and saved history.

Answer (score 0):

here's a django based Ajax Chat:

http://pythonhaven.wordpress.com/2009/04/26/django-powered-ajax-chat-part-1/